# How to add a DatagridTextColumn for display purpose

Tags: c#, xaml

Here in this code we use Binding to show a data column, how can I just show a blank column
for now, just for display, like "OTHER" as there is no data field for that as yet.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitId}"
                        Width="100*"
                        Header="Unit"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count}"
                        Width="80*"
                        Header="Missed"></DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data field is *null* you can use the [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.aspx):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitId, TargetNullValue='OTHER'}"
                    Width="100*"
                    Header="Unit"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Hi it seemed to have a problem with TargetNullValye--  Error 1 The property 'TargetNullValue' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. Line 26 Position 21. C:\OPTFDashboard\CFE.Dashboard.Common\Modules\MissedMedicareNote\TileView.xaml 26 21 CFE.Dashboard.Common

Comment: doh! I completely forgot about the binding base, I like this answer better, +1

Answer (score 1):

Well (if I understand your question correctly) you could wire up some mock Design Time Data to populate a binding in something existing, or you could just hard code something as a place holder like.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitId}"
                        Width="100*"
                        Header="Unit"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count}"
                        Width="80*"
                        Header="Missed"/>
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Other">
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="Other"/>
             </DataTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```